# Change zoom controls in a MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, android-mapview

I would like to change the predefined style of the zoom controls in my application to appear like the new zoom controls in the google maps application. See below:

[image]

How can I do it? I have been looking around and I haven't found anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly can you give more detail?

Comment: I would like to know if there is any easy way to change the look of the zoom buttons or I have to create new drawables and add them to the project, override the listeners and so on... but I guess I have to create my own zoom buttons

Comment: @jalv1039: u will get such buttons easily if u search on google ,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have four image drawables namely:

1. Zoom in **(+)** enable/disable
2. Zoom out **(-)** enable/disable

Put them in `MapView` layout an `ImageView`  or `Button` with background image as the above drawables.

Then you should assign onClickListeners like:

```
zoomIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mapView.getController.zoomIn()
        checkzoom();
    }
});

zoomOut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mapView.getController.zoomOut()
        checkzoom();
    }
});

public void checkzoom() {
    if(mapView.getZoomLevel()==1) // dont know if 0 or 1, just wrote it
    {
        zoomOut.setEnabled(false);
        // or u can change drawable and disable click
    }
    if(mapView.getZoomLevel()==18) {
        zoomIn.setEnabled(false);
        // or u can change drawable and disable click
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
[image: zoom in]
[image: zoom out]

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem this way: disabled built in zoom controls ([`setBuiltInZoomControls(false)`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29)), added my own buttons to UI and added handlers for click on button events.