# Android google maps button style

Tags: android, button, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to place a button on top of my google map, which is pretty easy.  However I would like it to look like the buttons google uses (zoom buttons, locate me button).  Is there a way I can 'cheat' and find the styles they used for their buttons.  Or has anyone else created this style before?

Comment: do you mean the skin of the buttons?

Comment: yeah, I could not find that anywhere

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you disassemble Google Play Services apk by using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), and look into `drawable`* folders, you will find the resources for these buttons among other resources.

For example, this is the drawable of the upper zoom button:
`res/drawable/maps_btn_zoom_up.xml`, and this is the "empty" button: `res/drawable/maps_btn_standalone.xml`. Looking at them, it is a lot easier to match their style.

The apk will probably be named like `com.google.android.gms-#.apk`, where `#` is some number; you can snatch it from a device which has Google Play Services installed by using `adb pull` command, it doesn't even require rooting if you know the exact file name.

#### Update

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwzrN1KmDAUDZ0hvTTNDbTRpZmc) is the archive with relevant resources for the empty standalone button, obtained by this way.
(sha256: `4b974a8c23bb8df54b9aa244489e8a7ab5d4d3e17d0c003f411bccbe8a75d622`)

And some numbers:
Button height and width is `38dp`
Shadow padding: top `1.5dp`
bottom `2.5dp`
side `2dp`

The background image is NOT nine-patch, but it's pretty easy to create one if you need.

Comment: Did you pull these files already?  If so can you just show the styles here?

Comment: I think the button height and width is subjective

Comment: Any suggestions on creating the shadow padding?

Comment: @AntiEarth standard techniques apply.

Answer (score 10):

I made this 9-patch image to use as background for the view that you want to be like a google maps button:

[image: google map style button background]

The color of the button content is #666666.

Here is an example of a custom view that looks like a google maps button using that background and that color for the text:

[image: example]

Comment: we have a winner!! 

Answer (score 3):

The button is a 70% semi-transparant white.

Or in HEX, #B3FFFFFF

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and found this question:[Change zoom controls in a MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912636/change-zoom-controls-in-a-mapview)

It appears a button is 2 images, a normal state and a clicked state.
For your purposes, you'd need to style the button yourself / 'cheat' the system. You can get a good template from either the google play lib or the support library.

Comment: I know how to create styles, but it will take me days to match their style.  I want the xml.