# Adding 2 Buttons relatively to one another on google maps api for android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I want to add 2 Buttons to my Android map app. They should be on the top left edge in front of my map just like the "find your position" button of google maps itself.

In my activity_maps.xml i have:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|top"
    android:text="@string/start_button_text"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="start_button_clicked"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/vorschlag_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_button"
    android:text="@string/vorschlag_button_text"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="vorschlag_button_clicked"
    />
```

My problem is the second button (@+id/vorschlag_button) is displayed on top of the first button (@+id/start_button) instead of right of the start button.

Also is there a way to align my buttons to the "my_position_button" of Google Maps API?

I also would like to have the same background color like the "my_position_button".

I get the error message on

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_button"
```

"Invalid layout param in a fragment."

Thank you for your help with this.

P.S.: Since it's not that much more: My whole activity_maps.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|top"
    android:text="@string/start_button_text"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="start_button_clicked"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/vorschlag_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_button"
    android:text="@string/vorschlag_button_text"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="vorschlag_button_clicked"
    />

</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Relative layout it will solve your issue. In this code if you want to button to bottom than add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
 to both button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:onClick="start_button_clicked"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="start_button_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vorschlag_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_button"
        android:onClick="vorschlag_button_clicked"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="vorschlag_button_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. For the other part. How can i reference the "my_position_button"?

Comment: If I use the above code my 2 buttons overlay over the "my location" button of google maps. That in itself is not a problem since if I use my text on the buttons they are not that large to influence the "my location" button. But they are 1 or 2 dpi lower than that button. So I'm looking for something like `android:layout_alignTop="mylocationbutton"`. I found the color of the location button is #B3FFFFFF at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457429/android-google-maps-button-style)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below code;

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            tools:context="com.user.newdemonearbyplace.MapsActivity" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center">

           <Button
            android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|top"
            android:text="@string/start_button_text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="start_button_clicked"
            />
           <Button
            android:id="@+id/vorschlag_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_button"
            android:text="@string/vorschlag_button_text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="vorschlag_button_clicked"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I just want to know how can you align those two buttons to location button by using this code?

Comment: It says: Namespace 'android' is not bound so i moved `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to `Linear Layout` that worked for adding 2 buttons. My problem with this solution is, that the 2 butons are below the map on a white square. So i have the buttons and the map sepparated instead of 2 buttons on top of the map. Sorry for not pointing that out in my question. I will edit that part.